# Where can I find Glassfish 4 source code?

Tags: glassfish-4

I am trying to debug my web application under Glassfish 4 but  since I only have jee7 API deps in my maven pom.xml I can not.

Is there a maven dependency that is linked to the glassfish source code? is there another way that I can get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is now finally available at https://github.com/javaee/glassfish through `git`. [Payara](https://github.com/payara/Payara) provides a compatible better maintained advancement.

Answer (score 14):

All GlassFish source code is available at:

https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/

The specific source code that you are looking for is at:

https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/branches/4.0/

The complete set of Java EE 7 maven coordinates are available at:

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Java+EE+7+Maven+Coordinates

Comment: From your answer I assume that I cannot get the source code from maven. (The coordinates have only the reference to the API from what I can see.)

Comment: The current source code can be found here: https://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show/trunk/main